# Error creating vpn tunnel GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We host our environments in GCP, we encounter a problem creating vpn tunnel from one env to another (process which used to work for us until couple of days ago)

We get the following error:

inconsistent local_addr_range (10.200.200.0/22 vs. )

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you should be able to create VPN tunnels regardless of the method used. Try [route-based VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns#simple_setup) by setting local and remote ranges to 0.0.0.0/0 for all the tunnels attached to the same gateway. Also, I would recommend you to use [Cloud Router(Dynamic routing)](https://cloud.google.com/router/docs/concepts/overview#dynamic_routing_for_vpn_tunnels_in_vpc_networks). You can also use this [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/vpnTunnels/insert) to create VPN tunnels.